# Hiding elements with javascript

Tags: javascript

On button click, I want to hide the div. How do i do it?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function button()
{
    var a = document.getElementById('approve');
    document.getElementById('p').innerHTML= 'Fred Flinstone';


}
</script>

<body>
<div id="hide">
<form>
<p id="p">heya</p>

<input type="button" id='approve' value="approve" onclick="button()"/>
<input type="button" id="reject" value="reject"/>
</form>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

SORRY FOR ASKING AGAIN...BUT COULDN'T FIND A BETTER METHOD. THANKS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.getElementById('hide').style.display = 'none';
```

This sets the CSS code `display: none;` on the div, which causes the browser's rendering engine to act like the element is not even on the page (*e.g.* it does not occupy any space). See the [CSS standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#propdef-display) for the official description.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use [Jquery](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) to make things super easy:

```
$("#approve").click( function() { 
    $("div#hide").hide()   //you can just use $("#hide") if you want
});
```

You can show the element whenever you want with `$("div#hide").show()`. This will save you from having to deal with browser inconsistencies and other crap so you can just focus on producing great readable code. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you use jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#approve').click(function() {
    $('#hide').hide();
  });
});
```